# Select most recent rows based on a DateTime field within 5 mins of current time

Tags: sql-server

In a SQL Server table, I have a DateTime field and every time I have a login failure for an external web service I write the current DateTime to the table.

I currently have code that parses through the returns and determines if there are > 2 failures within 5 mins. If so I have a flag to turn off calling of the web service. I am curious if there is a way I can just use sql to return the number of rows that are within 5 mins from the current time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will return all records that are less than five minutes old:

```
SELECT [Columns]
FROM [YourTable]
WHERE [DateTimeField] >= dateadd(minute, -5, getdate())
```

You can get more information on `DATEADD` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)  .

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyDateTimeField > DATEADD(mm, -5, GETDATE())
```